# Angular Redux @select() obs, can I then subscribe to that in my controller and will the pattern still unsubscribe me onDestroy?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, angular-material, observable

In Angular + Redux, I'm using the @select() to get an object called 'sectionAll' , I'm using that as my datasource for a table that I'm presenting, due to that, I need to pass it to my dataSource in the controller.

I'm using the constructor to subscribe to this 'sectionAll' observable.

My question is, if I use the @select() like this, will it destroy that subscription for me as well? or am I just using @select() wrong?

Edit:

I am using [@angular-redux/store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-redux/store) with Angular6

My constructor:

```
constructor(
    private adalService: AdalService,
    private service: DeliveriesService,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>
  ) {
    this.service.getSectionAll();
    this.sectionAll.subscribe(data => {
      (this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data)),
        (this.dataSource.sort = this.sort);
    });
  }
```

For the select part:

```
  @select() sectionAll;
```

Comment: What Redux library are you using ? Also some code should make the question clearer.

Comment: @AdrianFâciu thanks for your reply, I have edited the post and added some code + linked to the redux package I'm using.

Comment: Not familiar with this library but I believe the select decorator has nothing to do with the subscription itself. You are manually calling subscribe so it should be up to you to unsubscribe when needed.

Comment: I've been following a tutorial on it, and the point of the @select() decorator is to have that manage the subscription for you and instead you just add the | async pype in the view and you don't need to do anything else manually yourself in that context. 

Based on that I was wondering if it still cancels the subscription when I manually subscribe to it in the controller. Have looked through the documentation and searched google+stack. I guess I'll have to just test it out and see

Comment: The async pipe is the one that handles the unsubscribe. The [select decorator](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/src/decorators/select.ts) does not look to have anything to do with that.

Comment: That makes sense, then that answers my question. I have created a subscription object and put that constructor thing inside it, then on OnDestroy I'm calling: 
    this.sectionAllSubscription.unsubscribe();
If you want, post your comment as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with this library but I believe the select decorator has nothing to do with the subscription itself. You are manually calling subscribe so it should be up to you to unsubscribe when needed.

The async pipe is the one that handles the unsubscribe. The [select decorator](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/src/decorators/select.ts) does not look to have anything to do with that.